# Add subcollection of comments to desired post

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

So my comments are getting added to the correct post when the comment is made by the author on their own post, like so [image]

The Firestore code updated test:

```
Future<String> postComment(String postId, String text, String authorId,
      String name, String profilePic) async {
    String res = 'Some Error occurred';
    try {
      if (text.isNotEmpty) {
        String commentId = const Uuid().v1();
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('posts')
            .doc(authorId)
            .collection('userPosts')
            .doc(postId)
            .collection('comments')
            .doc(commentId)
            .set({
          'profilePic': profilePic,
          'name': name,
          'uid': authorId,
          'text': text,
          'commentId': commentId,
          'datePublished': DateTime.now()
        });
        res = 'success';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      res = e.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }
```

The desired structure of how the comments should get added: posts>UID(of poster)> userPosts(List of their posts)>postID>append comment to this postId as a subcollection.

Now, when I try to create a comment on a post made by another user, a new collection gets started with the ID of the post as its collection name. The postId it gets is the CORRECT id, however, the actual comment itself doesn't get added to the collection of THAT post. As you can see from the circle in the second image, the IDs match, however, the comment made doesn't go where it's intended, as it does in the first image. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Image with new code test, new collection gets made with the UID of the person who's post I am commenting on, doesn't get added to the subcollection of the actual postId

[image]

Comment: you can add a list of comments in userPosts collection, so you can fetch data easily and pass it into the model class instead of making a new sub-collection.

Comment: Did you try to click on the document ID in the console (the one in italic)?

Comment: @NehilKoshiya I'm wishing to display these comments on the postId on the app so would making a subcollection on the postId's not make this easier?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yeah so when I click on that, it does have all the data I need (The data shown in the Firestore code block) it's just not going in to the sub collection of that post, it's just making a new collection with the postId of the post I want it on :/

Comment: You probably use the wrong Post ID

Comment: All the ID's are correct, the issue is they aren't going in to the subcollection of the post

Answer (score 2):

When you're using the following reference:

```
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('posts')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('userPosts')
        .doc(postId)
        .collection('comments')
        .doc(commentId)
```

You're always trying to add data inside a document that corresponds to the currently authenticated user. That's the reason why when you are using the above code with another user, it writes the data to another location. Which location, the one that corresponds to that user.

If you want to write the data under a particular location, you have to create a reference that points to that particular location. For instance, if you want a user to write some data, in a document that corresponds to another user, you have to create a reference that contains that UID. That can be simply done, by adding the ID of the user who creates the post inside the document. In that way, doesn't matter which user reads the post, when you want to write the data, you can use the ID of the user who created the post, to construct the correct path.

Comment: Okay yeah that makes perfect sense and explains why this is happening. So when you say 'adding the ID of the user who creates the post inside the document' I already have the authorId of the poster (Can see in image 1 beneath the subcollection of comments). Do you mean to add this data to the onPressed from the comment screen that forwards this to the Firestore. Would seeing this code help or not?

Comment: If that is the ID of the user who created the post, then it's perfect. In that case, when another user reads the post (document), then use that ID that exists in the document to create the reference, and not its UID.

Comment: Ahh okay I think get you, are you suggesting to add another field with 'authorId'? Or get rid of the UID and use the authorId instead?

Comment: It sounds more appropriate `authorId` rather than a simple UID.

Comment: Okay so I accept the authorId now, I added updates just to the Firestore code block and the last image. Is this how you meant? This is so close to being done and I feel like I'm on the right lines. Just can't quite execute it :(

Comment: As long as you are using the `authorId` for creating a reference that points exactly where the comments are, it will solve the problem for sure. Besides that, be sure that also the other document ID (`postId`) is correct.

Comment: Twitter would be fine ;)

Comment: So regarding this question, can I help you with other information?